# How do transfer a hashmap to a list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I’m quite new to haskell. I want to access all values of a Hashmap recursively and store them in a List.

My Hashmap looks like:

```
data Hashmap k v = Leaf | Node (Hashmap k v) (k, v) (Hashmap k v) deriving (Show)
```

The function signature I tried is:

```
createList :: Hashmap k v -> [(k,v)]
```

The result for my "test" Hashmap:

```
Node (Node Leaf (1,34) Leaf) (2,65) (Node Leaf (3,21) Leaf)
```

will be:

```
[(1,34),(2,65),(3,21)]
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: What did you try? What went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, function in haskell is a list of pattern with actions. As you can see `createList` is of type `Hashmap k v -> [(k,v)]`, check the definition of `Hashmap`, it has two value constructor, so there are two patterns, you just need to deal each of them.

```
createList :: Hashmap k v -> [(k, v)]
createList Leaf = []
createList (Node l c r) = createList l ++ [c] ++ createList r
```

---

As `++` is inefficient, we can also use cons `:` to speed up.

```
list :: Hashmap k v -> [(k, v)]
list h = _list h []
  where
    _list Leaf xs = xs
    _list (Node l c r) xs = c : (_list l $ _list r xs)
```

Comment: Very sensible, and potentially very inefficient. Can you see why? Can you see how to fix it?

Comment: @dfeuer yes I am aware `++` is inefficient, and `:` can speed up the procedure. I added the code. And thanks very much for the feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think it is also possible to transform it back by using `foldr` ?

Comment: @PeterBerg with only one travel sequence there are many possibilities. To restore a binary tree, it usually takes 2 different travel sequence, such as preorder and inorder sequence.

Comment: @delta well, I thought about writing another function like: `listToHashMap :: [(k, v)] -> Hashmap k v`